# What is the best way to address the local server in a SQL connection string for ASP.net?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005

We have a 2K3 server we're using as both a database server AND a web server - fairly small traffic website.  I know, should be 2 separate servers, but isn't going to happen soon.

Currently, we have 2 NIC cards on this server, and in-house workers use custom apps that hit NIC1 all day long.  We also have the connection string for the website using that same IP address.

I'm wondering if it would benefit us at all to use the IP for NIC2 for the connection string for the website SQL, or if would be a waste of time.

Also, I'm wondering in a setup like this, where the SQL server IS the local server, is there a better way to address the server in the connection string than using the IP?

I'm simply trying to maximize the network we have and not create any bottlenecks.

Thanks much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use (local) as the server name that will default to using Named Pipes, which, on the same machine, has less overhead than the TCP/IP stack.

Comment: I had no idea... I thought that (local) and localhost were equivalent! Gotta update my connection strings. Thanks. :)

Comment: Note that even if you use a DNS name or IP address, it has no impact on the load on your NIC.  The network stack determines the address is local and the NIC device is not used.  +1 for named pipes bit, I did not know that detail.

Answer (score 0):

I would use localhost.  It will resolve faster than fully qualified domain name.

Answer (score 0):

I always use "." for local but sometimes it rejects in some servers (local) is working for all servers.